# Finding any duplicate element in array

Tags: java, arrays, search

I am trying to find element that is duplicated in an array. Program is intended to take user input.

Here is the code:

```
   package sortingattempt;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArraySimilar {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        int[] a = new int[100];
        int[] b = new int[5];
        int Duplicate = 0;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter size of array");
        int size = sc.nextInt();

        //Scanner elem = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input elements in array" +size);
        for(int j = 0;j<size;j++){
            a[j] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println(a.length);
        System.out.println("a[]" + a.toString());

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length;i++){
        b[0] = a[i];
        if (b[0] == a[i+1]){
            Duplicate = b[0];
            System.out.println(Duplicate);
        }
        i++;
        }
        System.out.println("No common variable");

    }

}
```

When I try to run it, its running properly till line where I ask user to give input. After entering input nothing is happening. Please indicate errors in program. Thank you.

Comment: Try inserting `sc.nextLine();` before `a[j] = sc.nextInt();`

Comment: No it did not work. I debugged program and found out that elements are not going in array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's happening is that you are not being prompted to enter a number  with a `System.out.println("Enter a number: ");` So you think the program is not working, when really it is just waiting for you to keep entering numbers. You may want to prompt with `System.out.println()`s on each iteration:

```
System.out.println("Input elements in array" +size);
for(int j = 0;j<size;j++){
    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    a[j] = sc.nextInt();
}
```

Also, your initializng your arrays before hand. Shouldn't you wait to get the user input for size, *then* initialize them?

```
int[] a; 
int[] b;

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter size of array");
int size = sc.nextInt();

a = new int[size];
b = new int[size];
```

Also, trying to print a.toString() will not give you your desired output. You have to iterate through it or do something like this

```
System.out.println("a[] " + Arrays.asList(a));
```

**Edit: To Compare**

You should just make the values equals in the first loop

```
for(int j = 0;j<size;j++){
    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    a[j] = sc.nextInt();
    b[j] = a[i];
}
```

Then in the bottom loop, compare in a nested loop

```
int dupCount = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++){
        if (b[i] == a[j]){
            Duplicate = a[j];
            System.out.println(Duplicate);
            dupCount = 0;
        }
    }
}
if (dupCount == 0)
    System.out.println("No common variable");
```

Comment: Thanks. It is now taking elements of input as Array. but I am getting an error now:

Exception in thread "main" a[][I@6bb1a986
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
 at sortingattempt.ArraySimilar.main(ArraySimilar.java:29)

Comment: Is this `if (b[0] == a[i+1])` line 29?

Comment: Yes. I am comparing elements there.

Comment: Im assuming you entered 5 for the size? You can see the problem when you try access `a[i + 1]`. The max `i` in the loop is 4, so when you try and add 1 you're trying to access `a[5]` which doesnt exist in an array of size 5. max index would be 4. You need to fix that +1. I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, so I can't really offer a solution.

Comment: I am trying to put each element in a[] at b[0] position and compare it with other elements in a[].

Answer (score 0):

Another error is that you need to delete the  i++ from this block of code

```
   Duplicate = b[0];
        System.out.println(Duplicate);
    }
    i++;  //delete that
    }
```

Also change that

```
  System.out.println("Input elements in array" +size);
for(int j = 0;j<size;j++){
    a[j] = sc.nextInt();
}
System.out.println(a.length);
System.out.println("a[]" + a.toString());//change that to a[j] and put it inside the loop.
```

I assume here that you want to print the elements of your array,so the a.toString won't do that.